# Execution failed on sql : insert dataframe to postgresql server

Tags: postgresql, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I'm trying to connect postgresql server and insert some dataframe to a table and this is my code

```
import datetime
import gzip
import logging
import os
import sys
import traceback
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from pandas.io.sql import SQLTable, pandasSQL_builder
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

c = psycopg2.connect(database="dc_integration", user="mastername", 
host="integrationdb.c46zksctipg7.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com", 
password="xxx")

d = {'project_key': [1, 2], 'project_name': [3, 4], 'update_date': 
['2016-06-22 19:10:28','2016-06-22 19:10:15']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_sql('project', con=c)
```

But I get this error

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': relation "sqlite_master" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?...
```

But I can read data from table. I don't know why it fails.

Comment: What's unclear about "*relation "sqlite_master" does not exist*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set your search_path to the schema where your table is located.

With either:

`ALTER USER username SET search_path = schema;`

In PostgreSQL.

Or set your search_path in the parameters of psycorg2.connect:

`search_path=schema`